# Screen starting on the bottom

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, screen, react-native-navigation

In react native, I'm using react navigation, and when i'm on the screen "X" and navigate to screen "Y", this is really good, but when i go back to screen "X", that is on the bottom, because when a navigate to screen "Y" i was on the bottom of the screen "X".

What i need: Everytime when i go back to screen "X" this start on the top.

I searched something about this in the docs, however i didnt found nothing about state of screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useFocusEffect` and a ref of your ScrollView to scroll back to the top when the screen comes into focus. Something like:

```js
  const scrollRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);

  useFocusEffect(
   useCallback(() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0, animated: false });
   }, [scrollRef])
  );

  // ...
  <ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
```